# Is it ok to power several op amps with the same pair of 9V cells?

Tags: operational-amplifier, batteries

I'm experimenting for the first time in the wonderful world of operational amplifiers. I'm processing signals in various ways - amplify, envelope detection, voltage differences, voltage-to-current, and so on.

Many of these steps use an op amp. Is it usually acceptable to power several (dual-supply) op amps with the  same pair of 9V cells?

Comment: Nit-pick: Most popular commercial *batteries* with a voltage >> 1.5V are comprised of multiple *cells*. You probably don't have a 9V *cell*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. In general all the circuitry on a board that uses the same voltage has the same supply. The only exception is when you have (for example) "digital" 5 V that will have noise on it and "analog" 5 V that is cleaner.

I am assuming that the batteries can supply enough current to power your several op-amps. 25 mA is fine. Higher currents will result lower mAh.